# Sending Email error reports from windows desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I have a windows desktop application running on clients machines using .NET 4.0. When an error occur, The application catches it and needs to send it to the support team b email.

The question is how to send an email with the full stack trace (including stacktrace for inner exception if there is one) using email?

I tried using the "Mailto:" but It wouldnt work when the body exceeds a certain length.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

[System.Net.Mail namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) contains classes that handle sending mail with the smtp protocol.  It may have a size limit, but I haven't found it yet in normal usage.

If you do manage to find a size limit, try writing the error log to a file an attaching it.

Also, as an easier way to do this, you might also consider [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to simplify logging in all manner of ways, including email with the [SmtpAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender.html).

Comment: The point is that I wanted this to come from the user's email. this will help them see exactly what is going to be sent and give me an email to reply back to.
I am not looking for something to send the emails from a predefined email like the case with log4net or system.net.mail